# How do I incorporate AWS and Python in my React Native App?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, react-native

I am building a React Native application that will be getting buoy data from [Coastal Data Information Program](https://cdip.ucsd.edu/m/documents/data_access.html#cdip-python-api). I am able to get the data from CDIP, but I want to incorporate AWS into my app. My goal is to have updated buoy data on pull refresh in my app. My app is completed for the most part, but now how do I get the buoy data onto my app? CDIP uses a Python API. This is my first time creating an app, so I'm not sure what is required to accomplish my goal. I've Googled around and it seems I can use AWS (API Gateway, AWS Lambda, and DynamoDB). I'm assuming I'll be using the endpoint in API Gateway to access the data. [Here is a layout of what I think I need to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9wax.jpg) Would I put the CDIP python code in the lambda function then the lambda function updates the database? Is a database necessary? Are there benefits of using a database? What's the purpose of a database? Can the lambda function update the database every time CDIP updates their data? I do not intend to store previous buoy readings; I just want to show the current buoy readings. Thanks in advance!

Addition: I am trying to get the following code to be executed by the lambda function and returned to my React Native App as a json object.

```
import netCDF4

# List of buoy names
buoy_names = ['KODIAK, AK', 'ANGELES POINT, WA', 'GRAYS HARBOR, WA', 'CLATSOP SPIT, OR', 'ASTORIA CANYON, OR', 'UMPQUA OFFSHORE, OR', 'HUMBOLDT BAY NORTH SPIT, CA', 'CAPE MENDOCINO, CA', 'POINT REYES, CA', 'SAN FRANCISCO BAR, CA', 'POINT SANTA CRUZ, CA', 'MONTEREY BAY WEST, CA', 'CABRILLO POINT NEARSHORE, CA', 'POINT SUR, CA', 'DIABLO CANYON, CA', 'SANTA LUCIA ESCARPMENT, CA', 'HARVEST, CA', 'TOPANGA NEARSHORE, CA', 'SANTA MONICA BAY, CA', 'SANTA CRUZ BASIN, CA', 'LONG BEACH CHANNEL, CA', 'SAN PEDRO, CA', 'SAN PEDRO SOUTH, CA', 'SAN NICOLAS ISLAND, CA', 'OCEANSIDE OFFSHORE, CA', 'DEL MAR NEARSHORE, CA', 'TORREY PINES OUTER, CA', 'SCRIPPS NEARSHORE, CA', 'MISSION BAY WEST, CA', 'IMPERIAL BEACH NEARSHORE, CA', 'POINT LOMA SOUTH, CA', 'OCEAN STATION PAPA', 'HANALEI, KAUAI, HI', 'WAIMEA BAY, HI', 'MOKAPU POINT, HI', 'BARBERS POINT, KALAELOA, HI', 'PEARL HARBOR ENTRANCE, HI', 'PAUWELA, MAUI, HI', 'KAUMALAPAU SOUTHWEST, LANAI, HI']

# List of buoy stations
stations = ['236', '248', '036', '162', '179', '139', '168', '094', '029', '142', '254', '185', '158', '157', '076', '222', '071', '103', '028', '203', '215', '092', '213', '067', '045', '153', '100', '201', '220', '155', '191', '166', '202', '106', '098', '238', '233', '187', '239']

i = 0
for stn in stations:
   # CDIP Realtime Dataset URL
   data_url = 'http://thredds.cdip.ucsd.edu/thredds/dodsC/cdip/realtime/' + stn + 'p1_rt.nc'

   # Open Remote Dataset from CDIP THREDDS Server
   nc = netCDF4.Dataset(data_url)

   # current waveHs - Significant Wave Height (meters). 1D variable based on: (waveTime). Range: 0-20.
   Hs = nc.variables['waveHs'][-1]

   # current waveTp - Peak Wave Period (seconds). 1D variable based on: (waveTime). Range: 0-40.
   Tp = nc.variables['waveTp'][-1]

   # current waveDp - Peak Wave Direction (degrees True). 1D variable based on: (waveTime). Includes compensation via (magnetic declination - INT(metaDeclination) to shift to degrees true. Range: 0-360.
   Dp = nc.variables['waveDp'][-1]

   # current sstSeaSurfaceTemperature - Sea Surface Temperature (Celsius). 1D variable based on: (sstTime). Range: -5.0 - 46.15.
   Sst = nc.variables['sstSeaSurfaceTemperature'][-1]

   # print buoy data
   print(buoy_names[i] + " - Station " + stn)
   i = i + 1
   print("Significant Wave Height: " + str(round(Hs * 3.28084, 1)) + "ft/" + str(round(float(Hs), 1)) + "m")
   print("Peak Period: " + str(round(float(Tp))) + "s")
   print("Peak Wave Direction: " + str(round(float(Dp))) + "°")
   print("Sea Surface Temperature: " + str(round((Sst * (9/5)) + 32, 1)) + "°F/" + str(round(float(Sst), 1)) + "°C\n")
```

Comment: You could create a CRON job to pull the data from the API and then save it to the database, from there you can have an API Gateway with Lambda functions to make GET request from the mobile application. If this is correct I could give a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a lambda for fetching data, returning data as response to your app and this lambda can be triggered with an API Gateway Endpoint which you can call from your React Native App.

Comment: Could you look at my addition to my question?

Comment: You can return the fetched data as json response to your App via the python code you shared above in the lambda. The architecture would still remain the same - your app hits the api gateway endpoint to trigger the lambda, the lambda fetches the data and then it returns data as json response to your app. As you just want to show the updated data you may not need to store it to a database. Do you have any other questions?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, how do you use netCDF4 in AWS? I'm not sure if it's supported. I tried using import netCDF4 while creating a lambda function but there is no module named netCDF4 in AWS.